# Rails 5 Paperclip Save Image from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, paperclip

I'm a total Rails newbie so apologies if this is a simple question, but I've been unable to find a clear answer. I'm trying to allow a user to attach an image to a post either by **uploading a file or entering the URL of an image using the Paperclip gem.**

File upload works fine, but using the URL method I receive a **'No handler defined'** error

**link.rb**

```
require "open-uri"

class Link < ApplicationRecord
    attr_reader :image_from_url
    has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "600x600>", thumb: "100x100#" }, default_url: "/images/:style/missing.png"
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

    def image_from_url=(url)
        self.image = URI.parse(url)
        @image_from_url = url
    end
end
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: link, local: true) do |form| %>
    <%= form.file_field :image, id: :link_image %>
    <%= form.text_field :image, id: :link_image_url %>
<% end %>
```

**links_controller.erb**

```
def create
    @link = current_user.links.build(link_params)
end

def link_params
  params.require(:link).permit(:title, :url, :description, :image, :slug)
end
```

I must confess that I don't fully understand what is happening at each stage of the process which is why I'm struggling to debug it.

Comment: As far as I understand:

When form submits it calls the image_from_url function in the model which then parses the url and saves is under the image column?

The form submits but its not saving the image and I'm not getting any error in the logs

Answer (score -1):

I am recommending carrierwave gem over paperclip. Easier to parse from link.

[Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave)